# Remove spacing between rows in longtable with p-columns following setspace

Tags: spacing, longtable, setspace, remove

I am using *longtable* with p-column (for the last column which contains long texts). I am also using *setspace*, as I want to increase the spacing in the main text. Even though *setspace* does not alter the spacing in the table environment, however, this is not the case with *longtable*. I found a suggestion to use \begingroup \arraystretch{0.5} \endgroup in order to bypass the spacing in the *longtable* introduced by *setstretch*. However, this does not work as expected when using **p-columns**. It removes the space between the rows of the table, but NOT the space between the rows created by the p-column setting. Is there any workaround?

Any other hints to make this table more presentable (e.g. how to remove the space between the 2 line at the bottom of the table), are welcome.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=3pt}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document} 
\setstretch{1.45}

\begin{center}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}

{\small\tabcolsep=1pt
\begin{longtable}{ccccp{5cm}}

\caption{List of Indicators}\\ 
\toprule\midrule

Category & Dataset & Ticker & Num & Description \\

\midrule \endfirsthead
\midrule \endhead 
\midrule \endfoot
\bottomrule \endlastfoot

Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\

\bottomrule
\label{table:vl}
\end{longtable}
}

\endgroup
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'd begin by replacing `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}` with `\setstretch{1.0}`. Also, don't encase a `longtable` environment in a `center`environment.

Comment: @Mico Thank you! This solves the issue. Why you wouldn't recommend encasing it inside `center`?

Comment: There's an excellent reason for not encasing a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment: The contents of `longtable` environments are centered horizontally *automatically*. Avoiding pointless code redundancy is always good, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @Mico Indeed, I cannot think of a better reason. XD Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed things from your MWE and may have carried bad practices along with my answer. Therefore, I suggest that you don't learn from my code, although it might help you solve your problem. Maybe someone can improve by editing my answer.

As [Mico suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615803/615807#comment1538275_615803) `\setstretch{1.0}` might solve spacing between rows and lines inside the *p-column*

To control spacing between the two last rules, you can use `\specialrule` in your original MWE. The `\bottomrule` works like:

```
\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{\belowbottomsep}
```

So, you can control the spacing above it by using the following instead:

```
\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{-9pt}{\belowbottomsep}
```

**(Edit: you don't even need `\specialrule` in your case)**

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=3pt}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} % <---- To have dummy text
\usepackage[width=16cm]{geometry}  % <---- So that the table has enough space to fit on the page and you see it centered

\begin{document} 
\setstretch{1.45}
\lipsum[1]  % <---- Dummy text (see that the stretching works here)

\begingroup
\setstretch{1.0}
\small
\tabcolsep=1pt
\begin{longtable}{ccccp{5cm}}

\caption{List of Indicators}\\ 
\toprule\midrule

Category & Dataset & Ticker & Num & Description \\

\midrule \endfirsthead
\midrule \endhead 
\midrule \endfoot
\midrule\bottomrule \endlastfoot

Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\[-2pt]
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons) \\
Non-Household Balance Sheets & x2 & TNWMVgh34JRM3 & 103 & Nonfinancial Corporate Business Sector Net Worth to Disposable Business Income (Percent) \\
Stock Markets & x3 & NIKKEI & 0 & Stock Average \\
Labor & x1 & UNEMPLRATE25o & 7 & Unemployment Level - Job Leavers (Thousands of Persons)
% Moved the \bottomrule up to \endlastfoot declaration
\label{table:vl}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\lipsum[1]  % <---- Dummy text (see that the stretching works here too)

\end{document}
```

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

#### Note:

The way you've written the top and bottom double lines is causing the table to start with the following widths:

```
\heavyrulewidth
\lightrulewidth
```

and to end with the following ones:

```
\heavyrulewidth
\heavyrulewidth
```

You probably want to use `\toprule\midrule` at the beginning and `\midrule\bottomrule` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed code. I know that `longtable` is not compatible with `threeparttable`. What would be a good method to add a simple table note at the end?

Comment: @CKara For this you need to use [`threeparttablex`](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttablex/threeparttablex.pdf). It has some differences from `threeparttable`, but the documentation isn't large and has examples that can help you out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!