# Changing the space between the rows of a cell spread over multiple rows in a longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable

I have a table spreading over two pages, so written by `longtable`. I want to set a more compact line spacing for my table, compared to the rest of my paper. I have used `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}`, that changes the line spacing between the rows properly. However, there are some cells that their text spread over more than one row, and for those ones, the line spacing does not change. How can I fix it?

I know one way is to use `\setstretch{1.0}` instead of `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}` (from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615803/remove-spacing-between-rows-in-longtable-with-p-columns-following-setspace) thread), however, I am using a document class that pops too many errors when I use  `setspace` package.

An example:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{longtable}{lp{10cm}}
 \caption{Notations.} \label{table_notations} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Notation} & \textbf{Definition}\\
    
    \midrule
    Indices and sets: & \\
    
    Row & In this cell I have a very long definition that will requires three rows of my table. The space between these three rows is not changed, and so is larger than the space between other rows. \\
    
    & This is another row.\\
    
    & This is another row.\\
    
    & This is another row.\\
    
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: the default spacing is 10pt text on 12pt baseline, if you multiply that by .8 you have 10pt text on 9.6pt baseline that is impossibly tight unless your text is all lower case so you will get uneven spacing as any capital letters or brackets will force the line spacing to change. Your comment `The space between these three lines is 1pt, but I want this to be changed to 0.8.` is misleading you are not changing the space from the bottom of one line to the top  of the next, you are changing the space from baseline to baseline and making it less than the size of the characters, which can not work.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle  Ijust corrected my sentence. So, how can I stretch the text and spaces between them in this setting?

Comment: you can put `\linespread{.9}` at the start of your p column entries

Answer (score 1):

Consider @David Carlisle suggestion in his comment and use `tabularray` package and its definition for `X` columns and used fonts in table:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text filler

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Notations.}, 
  label = {table_notations}
                    ]{rowhead = 1,
                      colspec = {@{} l X[j, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont] @{}},
                      row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                     }
    \toprule
Notation    
    &   Definition          \\
    \midrule
Indices and sets: 
    &                       \\
Row & In this cell I have a very long definition that will requires three rows of my table. The space between these three rows is not changed, and so is larger than the space between other rows.   \\
    & This is another row.  \\
    & This is another row.  \\
    & \lipsum[66]  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]